# Why does .CopyPicture return resolution different than manually copying a picture?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies Excel charts into Word, as images. This is accomplished by using `.CopyPicture xlScreen` on the relevant charts. It works well.

Is there anyway to maintain the same quality of image by hand? For the pictures copied in with the macro, the quality is as good as can be. I can go to max zoom in Word with no loss in quality. But when I try the "similar" method of just Right-click -> Copy, go to Word, Right-click -> Paste as Image, the quality is not maintained. It's especially noticeable if I were to print the Word document to PDF.

I've tried playing with the Word settings in Options -> Advanced -> Image Size and Quality, but to no avail. My goal is to be able to get these high-quality, "can zoom in with zero quality loss" charts into Word without resorting to a macro.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Good news everyone. I kept googling and stumbled upon [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/5sns91/exporting_an_excel_chart_without_losing_image/), asking the same question

Long story short, there is an easy fix. Rather than right-click on the image and copy, first just click on the image. Then, under the Home ribbon, Clipboard, click the dropdown next to Copy. Select "Copy as Picture". From there, the quality will be preserved when copying into Word!

[Copy as Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZunG.png)